# Create Function to Order by Multiple Columns in R

Tags: r, function, sorting

I can't figure out how to create a function in R that will order by multiple columns, one of which is a pass-through variable. Below is the code I have so far...

```
sorter <- function(df, col)
{
    df <- df[order(df[, col], "ColC", "ColD"), ]
}

sorter(mdf, 2)
```

Where mdf = my data frame and 2 = the column number I wish to sort.

What I am hoping it does is takes this:

```
ColA     ColB    ColC    ColD
Bob      41      84      95
Jane     41      77      100
Sam      35      84      100
Jeff     41      84      100
```

And turns it into this:

```
ColA     ColB    ColC    ColD
Sam      35      84      100
Jane     41      77      100
Bob      41      84      95
Jeff     41      84      100
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need `df[order(df$ColB), ]` ??

Comment: I would like it to be a function, wherein in the example I am passing-through column 2 ("ColB"), but it might be column 5 (presumably "ColE") or otherwise--but the secondary sorts will always be "ColC" and "ColD".

Comment: So you want to order according to 2 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

```
sorter <- function(df, col)
{
 return(df[order(df[, col]), ])
}

sorter(df, 2)
#ColA ColB ColC ColD
#3  Sam   35   84  100
#1  Bob   41   84   95
#2 Jane   41   77  100
#4 Jeff   41   84  100


sorter(df, 3)
#ColA ColB ColC ColD
#2 Jane   41   77  100
#1  Bob   41   84   95
#3  Sam   35   84  100
#4 Jeff   41   84  100
```

Comment: That works for sorting the one column, but what about the secondary sorts? Any idea how to add them in?

Comment: How are you planning to pass secondary sorts column numbers in the function?

Comment: No need to pass them through, as they are constants, but with your help I got it!    sorter <- function(df, col)
{
  return(df[order(df[, col], df[, "ColB"], df[, "ColC"]), ])
}